# Параметры для Controller из Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, html, mvc

Всем привет, у меня на Home View генерится список ссылок:

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.RegList)
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.registryName, "Index", "Registry", new { item.registryName }, new { item.registryID }) </li>
                }
            </ul>
```

Не понимаю - как в ActionLink указать параметры для контроллера и куда они дальше попадут?

Index я объявил так:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(object attr)
```

Но в attr у меня попадает object, который при касте в string становится null. Если входной тип string - тоже null.

Как передать параметр? Или я не к тому типу делаю каст? Хочу передавать массив.

Также непонятно, что в четвертом параметре - routeValues?

Описание метода:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.108).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны добавить все передаваемые параметры в routedValues

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.registryName, "Index", "Registry", new { name = item.registryName, id = item.registryID }) </li>
```

Comment: Ага, я уже разобрался, но все равно спасибо!